# Add rows to data frame that are multiplied values from data frame, python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame with 4x10 dimensions, the rows represent job categories 1-10, all jobs fall into one of the categories. The table states the probabilities that a person of a database has job 1-10 as a first job, as a second job etc.:

```
prob_all_dict = {'prob_1': {1.0: 0.03409090909090909,
  2.0: 0.022727272727272728,
  3.0: 0.045454545454545456,
  4.0: 0.5340909090909091,
  5.0: 0.06818181818181818,
  6.0: 0.011363636363636364,
  7.0: 0.13636363636363635,
  8.0: 0.06818181818181818,
  9.0: 0.045454545454545456,
  10.0: 0.03409090909090909},
 'prob_2': {1.0: 0.045454545454545456,
  2.0: 0.011363636363636364,
  3.0: 0.03409090909090909,
  4.0: 0.4659090909090909,
  5.0: 0.11363636363636363,
  6.0: 0.045454545454545456,
  7.0: 0.1590909090909091,
  8.0: 0.045454545454545456,
  9.0: 0.03409090909090909,
  10.0: 0.045454545454545456},
 'prob_3': {1.0: 0.1111111111111111,
  2.0: 0,
  3.0: 0.06349206349206349,
  4.0: 0.3968253968253968,
  5.0: 0.07936507936507936,
  6.0: 0,
  7.0: 0.19047619047619047,
  8.0: 0.1111111111111111,
  9.0: 0,
  10.0: 0.047619047619047616},
 'prob_4': {1.0: 0,
  2.0: 0,
  3.0: 0.043478260869565216,
  4.0: 0.391304347826087,
  5.0: 0.13043478260869565,
  6.0: 0,
  7.0: 0.08695652173913043,
  8.0: 0.2608695652173913,
  9.0: 0,
  10.0: 0.08695652173913043}}
prob_all = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(prob_all_dict)
```

From "prob_all" the data frame "out" is created by multiplying some cells with other cells: I already put the probabilities of the first job as a first row in a data frame and also the conditional probabilities of second jobs, depending on which job category people did in the first job, e.g. probability of having job category 2, provided job 1 category was 3 etc.

```
out=[prob_all['prob_1']]+[prob_all['prob_2']*prob_all['prob_1'].iloc[x] for x in range(0,10)]
out=pd.concat(out,axis=1)
out=(out.join(pd.concat([prob_all['prob_3']*out.iloc[x,1] for x in range(0,10)],axis=1))
        .join(pd.concat([prob_all['prob_3']*out.iloc[x,2] for x in range(0,10)],axis=1),rsuffix='x')
        .join(pd.concat([prob_all['prob_3']*out.iloc[x,3] for x in range(0,10)],axis=1),rsuffix='x')
        .join(pd.concat([prob_all['prob_3']*out.iloc[x,4] for x in range(0,10)],axis=1),rsuffix='x')
        .join(pd.concat([prob_all['prob_3']*out.iloc[x,5] for x in range(0,10)],axis=1),rsuffix='x')
        .join(pd.concat([prob_all['prob_3']*out.iloc[x,6] for x in range(0,10)],axis=1),rsuffix='x')
        .join(pd.concat([prob_all['prob_3']*out.iloc[x,7] for x in range(0,10)],axis=1),rsuffix='x')
        .join(pd.concat([prob_all['prob_3']*out.iloc[x,8] for x in range(0,10)],axis=1),rsuffix='x')
        .join(pd.concat([prob_all['prob_3']*out.iloc[x,9] for x in range(0,10)],axis=1),rsuffix='x')
        .join(pd.concat([prob_all['prob_3']*out.iloc[x,10] for x in range(0,10)],axis=1),rsuffix='x')
    ).values
out=pd.DataFrame(out).T
```

In a third step, I want to put the probabilities of job categories 1-10 depending on what a person did in the first, second and third job. I did this manually in the third block of code but want to "automatically" do this for all 1000 combinations:

```
out.iloc[11,0]*prob_all['prob_4'][1]
out.iloc[11,0]*prob_all['prob_4'][2]
out.iloc[11,0]*prob_all['prob_4'][3]
out.iloc[11,0]*prob_all['prob_4'][4]
out.iloc[11,0]*prob_all['prob_4'][5]
out.iloc[11,0]*prob_all['prob_4'][6]
out.iloc[11,0]*prob_all['prob_4'][7]
out.iloc[11,0]*prob_all['prob_4'][8]
out.iloc[11,0]*prob_all['prob_4'][9]
out.iloc[11,0]*prob_all['prob_4'][10]

out.iloc[11,1]*prob_all['prob_4'][1]
out.iloc[11,1]*prob_all['prob_4'][2]
out.iloc[11,1]*prob_all['prob_4'][3]
out.iloc[11,1]*prob_all['prob_4'][4]
out.iloc[11,1]*prob_all['prob_4'][5]
out.iloc[11,1]*prob_all['prob_4'][6]
out.iloc[11,1]*prob_all['prob_4'][7]
out.iloc[11,1]*prob_all['prob_4'][8]
out.iloc[11,1]*prob_all['prob_4'][9]
out.iloc[11,1]*prob_all['prob_4'][10]

out.iloc[11,2]*prob_all['prob_4'][1]
out.iloc[11,2]*prob_all['prob_4'][2]
out.iloc[11,2]*prob_all['prob_4'][3]
out.iloc[11,2]*prob_all['prob_4'][4]
out.iloc[11,2]*prob_all['prob_4'][5]
out.iloc[11,2]*prob_all['prob_4'][6]
out.iloc[11,2]*prob_all['prob_4'][7]
out.iloc[11,2]*prob_all['prob_4'][8]
out.iloc[11,2]*prob_all['prob_4'][9]
out.iloc[11,2]*prob_all['prob_4'][10]

out.iloc[11,3]*prob_all['prob_4'][1]
out.iloc[11,3]*prob_all['prob_4'][2]
out.iloc[11,3]*prob_all['prob_4'][3]
out.iloc[11,3]*prob_all['prob_4'][4]
out.iloc[11,3]*prob_all['prob_4'][5]
out.iloc[11,3]*prob_all['prob_4'][6]
out.iloc[11,3]*prob_all['prob_4'][7]
out.iloc[11,3]*prob_all['prob_4'][8]
out.iloc[11,3]*prob_all['prob_4'][9]
out.iloc[11,3]*prob_all['prob_4'][10]

out.iloc[11,4]*prob_all['prob_4'][1]
out.iloc[11,4]*prob_all['prob_4'][2]
out.iloc[11,4]*prob_all['prob_4'][3]
out.iloc[11,4]*prob_all['prob_4'][4]
out.iloc[11,4]*prob_all['prob_4'][5]
out.iloc[11,4]*prob_all['prob_4'][6]
out.iloc[11,4]*prob_all['prob_4'][7]
out.iloc[11,4]*prob_all['prob_4'][8]
out.iloc[11,4]*prob_all['prob_4'][9]
out.iloc[11,4]*prob_all['prob_4'][10]

out.iloc[11,5]*prob_all['prob_4'][1]
out.iloc[11,5]*prob_all['prob_4'][2]
out.iloc[11,5]*prob_all['prob_4'][3]
out.iloc[11,5]*prob_all['prob_4'][4]
out.iloc[11,5]*prob_all['prob_4'][5]
out.iloc[11,5]*prob_all['prob_4'][6]
out.iloc[11,5]*prob_all['prob_4'][7]
out.iloc[11,5]*prob_all['prob_4'][8]
out.iloc[11,5]*prob_all['prob_4'][9]
out.iloc[11,5]*prob_all['prob_4'][10]

out.iloc[11,6]*prob_all['prob_4'][1]
out.iloc[11,6]*prob_all['prob_4'][2]
out.iloc[11,6]*prob_all['prob_4'][3]
out.iloc[11,6]*prob_all['prob_4'][4]
out.iloc[11,6]*prob_all['prob_4'][5]
out.iloc[11,6]*prob_all['prob_4'][6]
out.iloc[11,6]*prob_all['prob_4'][7]
out.iloc[11,6]*prob_all['prob_4'][8]
out.iloc[11,6]*prob_all['prob_4'][9]
out.iloc[11,6]*prob_all['prob_4'][10]

out.iloc[11,7]*prob_all['prob_4'][1]
out.iloc[11,7]*prob_all['prob_4'][2]
out.iloc[11,7]*prob_all['prob_4'][3]
out.iloc[11,7]*prob_all['prob_4'][4]
out.iloc[11,7]*prob_all['prob_4'][5]
out.iloc[11,7]*prob_all['prob_4'][6]
out.iloc[11,7]*prob_all['prob_4'][7]
out.iloc[11,7]*prob_all['prob_4'][8]
out.iloc[11,7]*prob_all['prob_4'][9]
out.iloc[11,7]*prob_all['prob_4'][10]

out.iloc[11,8]*prob_all['prob_4'][1]
out.iloc[11,8]*prob_all['prob_4'][2]
out.iloc[11,8]*prob_all['prob_4'][3]
out.iloc[11,8]*prob_all['prob_4'][4]
out.iloc[11,8]*prob_all['prob_4'][5]
out.iloc[11,8]*prob_all['prob_4'][6]
out.iloc[11,8]*prob_all['prob_4'][7]
out.iloc[11,8]*prob_all['prob_4'][8]
out.iloc[11,8]*prob_all['prob_4'][9]
out.iloc[11,8]*prob_all['prob_4'][10]

out.iloc[11,9]*prob_all['prob_4'][1]
out.iloc[11,9]*prob_all['prob_4'][2]
out.iloc[11,9]*prob_all['prob_4'][3]
out.iloc[11,9]*prob_all['prob_4'][4]
out.iloc[11,9]*prob_all['prob_4'][5]
out.iloc[11,9]*prob_all['prob_4'][6]
out.iloc[11,9]*prob_all['prob_4'][7]
out.iloc[11,9]*prob_all['prob_4'][8]
out.iloc[11,9]*prob_all['prob_4'][9]
out.iloc[11,9]*prob_all['prob_4'][10]

out.iloc[12,0]*prob_all['prob_4'][1]
out.iloc[12,0]*prob_all['prob_4'][2]
out.iloc[12,0]*prob_all['prob_4'][3]
out.iloc[12,0]*prob_all['prob_4'][4]
out.iloc[12,0]*prob_all['prob_4'][5]
out.iloc[12,0]*prob_all['prob_4'][6]
out.iloc[12,0]*prob_all['prob_4'][7]
out.iloc[12,0]*prob_all['prob_4'][8]
out.iloc[12,0]*prob_all['prob_4'][9]
out.iloc[12,0]*prob_all['prob_4'][10]

out.iloc[12,1]*prob_all['prob_4'][1]
out.iloc[12,1]*prob_all['prob_4'][2]
out.iloc[12,1]*prob_all['prob_4'][3]
out.iloc[12,1]*prob_all['prob_4'][4]
out.iloc[12,1]*prob_all['prob_4'][5]
out.iloc[12,1]*prob_all['prob_4'][6]
out.iloc[12,1]*prob_all['prob_4'][7]
out.iloc[12,1]*prob_all['prob_4'][8]
out.iloc[12,1]*prob_all['prob_4'][9]
out.iloc[12,1]*prob_all['prob_4'][10]
```

Can someone help me with this please? I've been stuck on this for a long time. Thank you!

Comment: Can you explain what you’re trying to do with all these multiplications? Maybe write mathematically what you’re trying to compute? It’s very confusing to me what you’re trying to do and also what size the result ends up being (looks like you’re adding a new column for each value in each row, so a final dataframe with 41 columns?)

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I added some explanations to the question and hope that it makes sense to you, it's difficult to explain in a couple of words...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use loops to change the indices and append each row to the dataframe

```
for i in range(11, 13):
    for j in range(10):
        out.loc[len(out)] = [out.iloc[i, j] * prob_all['prob_4'][k] for k in range(1, 11)]
```

The `out` calculations can be simplified as well

```
for i in range(1, 11):
    out = out.join(pd.concat([prob_all['prob_3'] * out.iloc[x, i] for x in range(0, 10)], axis=1), rsuffix='x')
out = pd.DataFrame(out.values).T
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!! The second block of code works fine! But if I run the first one it gives me the same data frame as the second one, should it be like that?

Comment: @Theresa_S the first block is based on the code you posted which is incomplete, for example it will throw `IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds` on the df in the question. You need to do something with the returned value.

Comment: I just fixed the prob_all by replacing the nans with 0s. What else would you need? What do you mean by "You need to do something with the returned value"?

Comment: @Theresa_S what do yo want to do with the results of `out.iloc[11,0]*prob_all['prob_4'][1]` for example?

Comment: Ah, I want to have e.g. out.iloc[11,0]*prob_all['prob_4'][1], out.iloc[11,0]*prob_all['prob_4'][2], out.iloc[11,0]*prob_all['prob_4'][3], ... , out.iloc[11,0]*prob_all['prob_4'][10] in one row of the out dataframe, below the first 110 rows that I created with your second code block. Then I want the values of out.iloc[12,0]*prob_all['prob_4'][1], out.iloc[12,0]*prob_all['prob_4'][2], ... , out.iloc[12,0]*prob_all['prob_4'][10] as a row below, then out.iloc[13,0]*prob_all['prob_4'][1] etc. until out.iloc[999,0]*prob_all['prob_4'][1]